# Why a file is empty after writing to it?

Tags: python, multithreading, file, tkinter

I got a tkinter app and a thread which writes some data to a file. If I let the thread finish it's job, the file is empty. If I terminate the program before the thread is done (clicking the red square in pyCharm) the file is filled with the data till the point of termination. Here is a code to reproduce the problem:

```
import tkinter as tk
import _thread
import numpy as np

img_list = []


def create_img_list():
    for i in range(1000):
        img = np.random.rand(385, 480)
        img = img * 65535
        img = np.uint16(img)
        img_list.append(img)


def write_to_file():
    f = open("test.Raw", "wb")
    for img in img_list:
        f.write(img)
    f.close()


root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text="Click Me", command=_thread.start_new_thread(write_to_file, ())).pack()
create_img_list()
root.mainloop()
```

What is going on here and how do I fix it?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly is going on but you could just remove the f.close() and it should fix your problem.

Comment: You are calling `write_to_file()` before `create_img_list()`, `img_list` is still empty.

Comment: @AustinReedVlog just tried it, same result.. file is empty

Comment: @Guy First I initialize the list, then on a button_click it starts to write

Comment: You have two threads accessing a shared resource (`img_list`) concurrently. You need use a `Lock` to coordinate access to this shared resource.

Comment: @martineau which 2 threads?

Comment: The one running `write_to_file()` and the main one that runs `create_img_list()` along with the GUI.

Comment: Dont use the `_thread` module directly. You _never_ want to access  underscore `_modues` directly, unless you know _exactly_ what you are doing. Use `threading` instead: `command=threading.Thread(None, write_to_file, ()).start.`

Comment: @martineau yes but im starting to write only after the list is fully initialized

Comment: Then why run it in a separate thread?

Comment: @Dan *First I initialize the list, then on a button_click it starts to write* No, you aren't. `write_to_file` is being called first. You can check it by adding `print(name)` to each function.

Comment: @martineau this is just a sample code to reproduce the problem..

Comment: How is write_to_file being called first? It looks like the user has to press the button for that to be called.

Comment: @quamrana I think you're thinking of `command=write_to_file`, but that's not what they're doing.

Comment: @MegaIng tried it with threading.Thread... same problem an empty file

Comment: @Dan, what did you try with threading? What I showed in my comment? Because that works for me.

Comment: @MegaIng ye u right, it works with the sample code... but in my real code (which is not very different from sample) it doesn't, only difference is i pass some arguments

Comment: While the thread is running i can see the file getting filled (its size getting bigger) but once the thread is done the file resets to empty

Comment: add `print(img_list)` to `write_to_file()` and you will see that this function is executed at start - without clicking button - even before runs `create_img_list()` which creates list so `write_to_file()` writes empty list. You create and start thead in `command=` and you assign result from thread to `command=` but you should assign normal function which will later create thread and start it. Or use `lambda` for this - `command=lambda:_thread.start_new_thread(write_to_file, ())`

Comment: @AustinReedVlog Why do you think removing `f.close()` will fix the problem? Doing `f.close()` is correct and should not be removed. You need to properly close the file after writing to it. You should always explicitly close anything you open unless you are using a `with` statement. From what I can see the problem exist due to the button command. It needs a lambda.

Answer (score 1):

When I add `print(img_list)` to `write_to_file()` I see that this function is executed at start - without clicking button - even before `create_img_list()` runs (which creates list) so `write_to_file()` writes empty list.

You use `command=` incorrectly. It needs function name without `()` (so called "callback") but you run function and you assign its result to `command=`. Your code works like

```
result = _thread.start_new_thread(write_to_file, ()) # it executes function at start

button = tk.Button(root, text="Click Me", command=result).pack()
```

but you need

```
def run_thread_later():
    _thread.start_new_thread(write_to_file, ())

button = tk.Button(root, text="Click Me", command=run_thread_later).pack()
```

Eventually you can uses `lambda` to create this function directly in `command=`

```
button = tk.Button(root, text="Click Me", command=lambda:_thread.start_new_thread(write_to_file, ())).pack()
```

---

**BTW:** you have common mistake

```
button = Button(...).pack()
```

which assign `None` to variable because `pack()`/`grid()`/`place()` return `None.

If you need access `button` later then you have to do it in two lines

```
button = Button(...)
button.pack()
```

If you don't need access `button` later then you can skip `button()

```
Button(...).pack()
```